# Do I suspect he is regretful now, or I guess he will be regretful in the future in saying "He may regret having quit his job"?

Tags: modality

> He may regret having quit his job.

Does this mean

> It is possible that he now wishes he hadn't quit his job.

or

> It is possible that he will eventually wish he hadn't quit his job.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He may regret having quit his job.

That 'may' indicates a form of [modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality) that has to do with possibilities, called [epistemic modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality). In other words, 'may' shows how much the speaker believes in what they're proposing in their sentence.

However, both of your proposed interpretations are possible, since there isn't a location in time specified. He may regret the decision now, or in the future.

If the speaker needs to highlight that the time of regret is possibly **now**, they can use [the progressive aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_progressive_aspects#English):

> He may **be regretting** having quit his job.

. . . or include "now" in the original sentence. [Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)) can be used to indicate the action  being done in the past:

> He may **have regretted** having quit his job (already).

To point to future, simply an inclusion of **"in the future"** in the original sentence would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

> He may regret having quit his job.

could also be written:

> Having quit his job, he may regret it.

*Having quit his job* means that he already quit.

> Having considered your question, I decided to write an answer.

I completed my review of your question before answering.

The possibility part, introduced by *may*, only involves *regret*, and has no function in the timing of events.